# WindowsForms - searching for "Parameters" in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#

I want to read some user input from a richtextbox in WindowsForms.

I want the user, to write text by a specific format, example:

```
string text = "[3,true]#[5,false]#[9,false]"; // users input from the textfield
```

So what I want, is a List of strings.

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> tempList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
```

This list is filled by the values above

```
tempList .Add(new Tuple<string, string>("3", "true"));
tempList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("5", "false"));
tempList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("9", "false"));
```

And I do not really know, how to search substrings from a big text.

This is what I got so far:

```
private string FindNeighbourInText(string source, string start, string end)
{
    int startPos;
    int endPos;
    if (source.Contains(start) && source.Contains(end))
    {
        startPos = source.IndexOf(start, 0) + start.Length;
        endPos = source.IndexOf(end, startPos);
        return source.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos);
    }
    else
        return string.Empty;
}
```

But it seems, that this is not the correct thing, I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ideal job for Regular Expressions.
You can use this pattern to capture all the variables, with named groups for the number and value `\[(?<number>.*?),(?<value>.*?)\]`.

It looks for strings of characters between `[` and `]`.
Those characters are made up of the pattern `(characters),(characters)`.
The characters before the comma are placed in a group named `number`, and the ones after the comma are named `value`.

Then it is just a matter of looping through all the matches and looking at the value of the captured named groups.

In code it would look like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = "[3,true]#[5,false]#[9,false]";
    var pattern = new Regex(@"\[(?<number>.*?),(?<value>.*?)\]");

    foreach (Match match in pattern.Matches(data))
    {       
        Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups["number"]} = {match.Groups["value"]}" );
    }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
3 = true
5 = false
9 = false
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MLpZGp) for it.

Comment: Wow this is really awesome :O Could you explain me this line of code `Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups["number"]} = {match.Groups["value"]}" );` ? Because I want to divide these 2 values into string variables. string numberText = ...; and string boolText = ...;

Comment: That line is equivalent to `Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["number"] + " = " + match.Groups["value"] );`, using the new [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Visual Studio 2017.  If you want to put them in variables, just do `var number = match.Groups["number"] `.